# Please re-open this question about Hulk vs Superman

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-question, closed-questions, vote-to-reopen

[Hulk vs. Superman - did they ever fight? Who won?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/38046/hulk-vs-superman-who-would-win-and-why)

While this LOOKS like a Shark-vs-Gorilla, it is actually fully and eminently answerable... because **there WERE comics in which Superman fought Hulk**:

- **Fight #1:** 1981 "[DC and MARVEL present: #28: SUPERMAN and SPIDER-MAN](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002K7FTAM)".

  - That comic featured a fight between Hulk and Superman.
  - Hulk gets all hulked-out... but can't hurt or move Superman.
  - In the end, he's so exhausted, he converts back to Bruce Banner.

  **This clearly shows Superman winning.**

  ---
- **Fight #2:** 1996 "MARVEL COMIC vs DC #3: The showdow of the century".

  - It was a part of this special series: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DC_vs._Marvel
  - Hulk vs Superman were one of the 5 fights which were decided by fan votes.
  - Superman made Hulk bleed from mouth and then knocked him out.

  **This clearly shows Superman winning.**

  ---
- **Fight #3:** 2001 "The Incredible Hulk vs. Superman".  Play-by0

  - Hulk hits Superman pretty hard - knockdown.
  - Hulk throws Superman high up. No damage.
  - Superman flies fast and knocks Hulk away, through a bunch of rock. Knockdown.
  - Superman twirls Hulk, and throws him far far away
  - They fight some more, no damage.
  - Both are blasted from the sky with some rockets shot by presumably militarty. Both had wind knocked out of them.
  - Hulk *throws* a bunch of rockets at Superman.
  - All the while Superman tries to tell Hulk they were set up and shouldn't fight. While punching him, successfully :)
  - Then Hulk listened.

This one was more even handed but **Superman has an edge** as he hurt/knocked down/punched off Hulk more than vice versa.

Comment: I'm no expert, but I [did find some discussion](http://forums.superherohype.com/showthread.php?t=303926) of a Marvel/DC crossover where the two fought.  So perhaps the question can be saved.  I believe it needs some edits to salvage it, though.

Comment: @Beofett - see my (deleted) answer to this question on 2 cases where they fought. What did you have in might re: salvaging?

Comment: see my edits and comments on the question.

Comment: @Beofett - love the edits (shocker!)

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to Beofett's masterful edit, was re-opened.